# How to Not to Save State in Latest Navigation Component Android Library - Java

Tags: java, android, mvvm, androidx, android-architecture-navigation

Component used: Navigation

Version used: 2.5.2

I would like to know if there's a way to stop saving states of different navigation views in the latest navigation library. As this is a default behavior in the library but I am in a position where I need to prevent this saving state behavior.

Your response will be highly appreciated.

I tried changing the default behavior with actions in navigation graphs in multiple navigation files but unable to achieve the required functionality.

Comment: Why do you want users, in just your app, to have a different experience from every other app and lose the user's information?

Comment: Actually, I want users to select an option (Go to A or Go to B) whenever they click on the home menu in the navigation bar.